# Rails5: How to show access log to public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I want to see logs of public directory access, how can I do that?
For example, I have a file named `public/uploads/image/thumbnail.png` then I want to see access logs to the file.

I'm using Rails5 and puma in my local dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem by writing a middleware.

```
class StaticLog
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    puts 'STATIC FILE ACCESS: ' + env['REQUEST_PATH']
    res = @app.call(env)
    res
  end
end
```

then in `config/application.rb` :

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, 'StaticLog'
```

I appended my middleware class in the end of the `application.rb` since it's temporary.

Comment: I had to give the class name without the quote to get it working.